# Why is a big loop within a small loop faster than a small loop within a big one?

Tags: perl, loops, wolfram-mathematica

This is my Perl code

```perl
$big=10_000_000;
#A:big loop outside
my $begin_time = time;
foreach my $i (1..$big) {
        foreach my $p (1..10){
        }
}
my $end_time = time;
my $t1=$end_time-$begin_time; 

#B:small loop outside
my $begin_time = time;
foreach my $i (1..10){
     foreach my $p (1..$big){
     }
}
my $end_time = time;
my $t2=$end_time-$begin_time; 

#output
print $t1;
print "\n";
print $t2;
```

> t1=8 seconds
>   t2=3 seconds

And the mathematica code:

```
Timing[Do[2, {i, 1, 10}, {j, 2*1, 10^7}]]
output:{14.328, Null}
Timing[Do[2, {j, 1, 2*10^7}, {i, 1, 10}]]
output:{30.937, Null}
```

Why does the big loop outside take more time?

Comment: `perl -MO=Concise script.pl` gives more opcode in the first case.

Comment: My native language is not English ,but You understand what I mean very well!Thanks for your editing

Comment: It should be pointed out if you do some real calculation in the loop the performance might very well reverse - don't draw a sweeping conclusion from this.

Comment: can you give me an example code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a certain amount of overhead in executing the inner loop (initialising the variable; making the checks to see if it should end) and in the first case, you are losing this overhead 10,000,000 times; in the second, you are only doing it 10 times.

EDIT:
Let `s` be the time to setup a loop (e.g. initialise a variable) and `i` the time to iterate a loop (e.g. test the end condition).  Then:

**Big Inner Loop**

```
T = s1 + 10 * ( i1 + s2 + 10,000,000*i2 )
  = s1 + 10*i1 + 10*s2 + 100,000,000*i2
```

**Big Outer Loop**

```
T = s1 + 10,000,000 * ( i1 + s2 + 10*i2 )
  = s1 + 10,000,000*i1 + 10,000,000*s2 + 100,000,000*i2
```

**Difference**

```
diff = 9,999,990*i1 + 9,999,990*s2
```

So the iteration time of the outer loop (`i1`) and the set-up time of the inner-loop (`s2`) are both performed 9,999,990 times more with the big outer loop than with the big inner loop.

Comment: It's 10,000,000 times, not 10,000. And the time taken to check to see if a loop should end is identical in both cases: it's just the initial loop setup and later tear-down that is different

Comment: @Borodin - sorry, misread the number.  Added more detail about setting-up and iterating the loops.

Comment: @Borodin: the inner loop is indeed checked the same number of times in both cases. The outer loop is checked 10 times in one case and 10E6 times in the other case.